# Setup rpy2 with Python 3.6 and R 3.4.2 in Anaconda

Tags: python, r, anaconda, rpy2

I am unable to setup rpy2 with Python 3.6 and R 3.4.2 in Anaconda.

When I run **conda install rpy2** I get the following:

"Solving package specifications: .
Warning: 2 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):

- r::rpy2-2.9.0-py36r342h301bfa9_0
- defaults::rpy2-2.9.0-py36r342h301bfa9_0

All requested packages already installed."

Running **import rpy2** works fine.

But when I run **import rpy2.robjects as ro**, I get the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rpy2.robjects'

Any help would be appreciated!